# Opencart ‒ How to display all the "Stock Status" values on category except for "Out Of Stock"?

Tags: opencart

Opencart 2.x/3.x

Hi, friends!
My head is boiling like a teapot :( Help please to solve the problem.

I want to show all values from "Stock Status" in category page but do not show "Out Of Stock" when the quantity of the product more and less zero.

My code:

```
product.php - in controller
Before: if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
Add: $data['stock_quantity'] = $product_info['quantity'];
     $data['stock_text'] = $product_info['stock_status'];

After: $data['products'][] = array(
Add: 'quantity'       => $result['quantity'],
     'stock_text'     => $result['stock_status'],

category.php - in controller
After: $data['products'][] = array(
Add: 'quantity'       => $result['quantity'],
     'stock_text'     => $result['stock_status'],

product.tpl - in template
<?php if ($stock_status_id != 5) {
echo $product['stock_text']; }
?>
```

Tell please, which correct code do I need to specify so that i can see all statuses except for "out of stock"(`id=5`) ?

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKwOW.png)

Comment: please post the `catgeory.tpl` code that you've modified, it might be the button text is getting replaced in your code logic.

Comment: @RohitBatra i edit my post. Please take a look.

Comment: also share the `template` file. maybe the `button_text` is being set by `stock_text`

Comment: @RohitBatra of course I changed the "button_cart" button to "stock_text", this result is visible on the image in my first message. As you can see, the statuses are displayed as expected, but why is "out of stock" displayed when there should be "add to cart"? How to do it? I think that in my code something is missing.

Comment: Anybody please tell me how to correctly insert "status_id = 3" so that it does not show up among other statuses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In catalog/model/catalog/product.php

add:
    `'stock_status_id'  => $query->row['stock_status_id'],`

after:
    `if ($query->num_rows) {
        return array(
                'product_id'       => $query->row['product_id'],
                'name'             => $query->row['name'],`

In catalog/controller/product/category.php

add:
    `if($result['stock_status_id'] == 5){
        $stock = '';
     }else{
        $stock = $result['stock_status'];
     }`

before:
    `$data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                'thumb'       => $image,`

add:
    `'stock'       => $stock,`

after: 
    `$data['products'][] = array(`

In category.tpl

add:

```
<?php echo $product['stock']; ?>
```

at place you want to display stock but in $product foreach loop.

To display stock_status as your add_to_cart button:

In catalog/model/catalog/product.php

add:
    `'stock_status_id'  => $query->row['stock_status_id'],`

after:
    `if ($query->num_rows) {
        return array(
                'product_id'       => $query->row['product_id'],
                'name'             => $query->row['name'],`

In catalog/controller/product/category.php

add:
    `if($result['stock_status_id'] == 5){
        $data['button_cart'] = $result['stock_status'];
     }else{
        $data['button_cart'] = '';
     }`

before:
    `$data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                'thumb'       => $image,`

This will change your 'add to cart' button to stock status and if stock_status_id ==5 then text will remain as 'add to cart'